# Comfolding Origins

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, visual

[image]

Unfortunately, this image is too big for me to provide a transcription.

Hint:

> Refer to title.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> your username, SNY,

because

> if you "fold" (reflect) all the cells across the middle square in the image, then do the same thing in the other direction, you get the following:
>  [image: SNY]
>  where each square has been colored according to where it came from (gray = original, purple = horizontal flip, red = vertical flip, yellow = horizontal+vertical flip).

Comment: oooh that's clever!